# Programming language per country

Tags: feature-request, survey-2019

To complement the average salaries for languages, I believe an analysis is also needed of how languages fare in each country.

Is it that in the US - Clojure is used more? And Java is used more offshore?

Comment: 'more than what'? To be clear, Clojure is used more in the US than abroad. But Clojure is not used more than Java. Yes, Java is very common in South Asia, it has displaced C as the first language people learn, in many countries.

Comment: Java is pretty popular in the US still- I see more Java positions posted online than for any other language in my area.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. It's about how much salary the programmers of each language gain per country, which language is more used in each country, which language is more used for a specific task or in a specific way, or you're asking it all together?

Comment: I'm more interested in: *how much salary the programmers of each language gain per country, which language is more used in each country*.